# Непонятная ошибка

Tags: php

Не понимаю. В коде

```
<?php
echo "<img src="1.jpg">";
?>
```

Не выходит пишет

> `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DNUMBER, expecting ',' or ';' in Z:\home\test1.ru\www\Battle.php on line 3`

Кто исправит поставлю верно, палец вверх, 5 рейтинга отдам

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правильно ругается - кавычки внутри строки нужно экранировать:

```
<?php echo "<img src=\"1.jpg\">"; ?>
```

Comment: лучше уж `<?php echo '<img src="1.jpg">'; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

А еще можно так:

```
<img src="1.jpg">
```

и на мгновение забыть про PHP
ну а если циферка динамическая то так:

```
<img src="<?=$i?>.jpg">
```

а уже в XHTML и HTML5 вроде как надо так делать:

```
<img src="1.jpg" />
```